# Is it true that $\{ z = x^2 + y^2 : x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0 \} = \{ x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0 \}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I'm trying to work on the formalization of optimization problems of the form: "determine $\max\{f(x):g(x) = 0\}$", i.e., maximize $f(x)$ subject to $g(x) = 0$, but I'm having a bit of a hard time with how the set theory algebra works if we remove the requirement for a maximum and look to find what is designated by only $\{f(x):g(x) = 0\}$. Here's my question:

Suppose I have an equation of real variables $z = x^2+y^2$. The graphical representation of this equation is, for any fixed $z$, a circle. So if I increase or decrease the size of $z$, I increase or decrease the size of the circle.

Consider $\{ z = x^2 + y^2 : x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0 \}$, where the constraint on the circle equation has the graph of Descartes' folium. Since I can arbitrarily increase or decrease the size of the circle so as to make it intersect all the possible points of $x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0$, doesn't this imply that  $\{ z = x^2 + y^2 : x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0 \} =  \{ x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0 \}$, since the circle equation will eventually intersect all possible points of  $x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0$?

I know I'm doing something wrong in this reasoning somewhere, so I was hoping someone could throw me a hint on what I'm doing wrong. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: It's not your reasoning that's at fault, it's your notation. Neither of the set definitions in your title makes sense, as far as I can see.

Comment: @TonyK thank you for your answer! I was attempting to see how the optimization problem $\max \{f(x) : g(x) = 0 \}$ changed if I removed the requirement to find the maximum and instead attempted to find what is designated by $\{f(x) : g(x) = 0 \}$, but I've gotten confused along to way... hopefully I'll work things out

Comment: In total agreement with @TonyK, I would suggest that all your “$\{blah:blooh\}$” statements should be of form $\{x\in gorp: blooh(x)\}$, or some very close variant of this. In particular, you say nowhere what kind of animals $x$, $y$, and $z$ were supposed to be.

Comment: @Lubin thank you for your answer, I will work on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have highlighted this very well, but I'll put an answer for the sake of it.

From what I can tell, you're trying to create a new variable $z$. This variable takes the value $x^2+y^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are the real solutions of $x^3+y^3-3xy=0$.

First, you can create the set of real solutions of $x^3+y^3-3xy=0$ by defining a set (I'll call it $S$), where

$$S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^3+y^3-3xy=0\}$$

This will give you the set of points $(x,y)$ such that they solve that equation. So $S$ will look like

$$S=\{(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3), \ ...\}$$

*Fun fact: the graph of $S$ is called the [folium of Descartes when $a=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folium_of_Descartes)!*

You then want $x^2+y^2$. To express this, the following comes to mind:

$$z=\{x^2+y^2: (x,y) \in S\}$$

Note that this is the **set** of values of $z$ and not each value of $z$.

Comment: thank you for the answer! this was exactly it!